# Is melee attacks' reach always written?

Tags: combat, pathfinder-2e, creature-size, reach, melee-combat

So, a group of mine made this doubt pop up: do huge creatures have reach just because of their size?

From what I understand, a creature has reach on a melee attack only if it's written as this one (an [adult red dragon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=137) used as an example)

> jaws +29 / +24 / +19 (fire, magical, reach 15 feet)

The dragon is huge and has a different reach on every melee attack.

So a [greater nightmare](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=309) - although huge - should not have reach on an attack written like this, right?

> jaws +24 / +19 / +14 (evil, magical)

Again, to summarize: is melee attacks' reach always written in the creature's stat block?

Edit: the first answers both seem valid, but they diverge. Any official quote would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158421/how-to-determine-if-and-how-a-creatures-reach-should-be-modified-when-its-size - however, this question is only covering spells and effects that change sizes, so I don't think it's a dupe - if anything, that question is a dupe of this one (by being a sub-category)

Answer (score 8):

## Reach Should Always Be Listed

Operative word here being "should" - I've not yet seen a creature where it seems like it was a mistake it wasn't.

The [rules for reach as it corresponds to size](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=445) say this:

> Table 9–1 also lists the **typical** reach for creatures of each size...

> Table 9-1: Size and Reach
>
> | Size | Space | Reach (Tall) | Reach (Long) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Tiny | Less than 5 feet | 0 feet | 0 feet |
> | Small | 5 feet | 5 feet | 5 feet |
> | Medium | 5 feet | 5 feet | 5 feet |
> | Large | 10 feet | 10 feet | 5 feet |
> | Huge | 15 feet | 15 feet | 10 feet |
> | Gargantuan | 20 feet or more | 20 feet | 15 feet |

The table shows the **typical** reach of a Huge (Long) creature like the Greater Nightmare is 10 feet. However... note the word **typical** means that this is more of an FYI of what to expect than an actual rule. These rules in turn reference the [Range and Reach rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=352) on page 455 of the CRB:

> Your reach is **typically** 5 feet, but weapons with the reach trait can extend this. Larger creatures **can** have greater reach; for instance, an ogre has a 10-foot reach.

Again, none of the language here implies that it's all Large or larger creatures have reach! Importantly, the [referenced Ogre](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=317) explicitly calls out Reach in its stat block. This would be totally unnecessary if we were to assume the typical Reach.

**RAW, Reach is never assumed to be anything but 5 feet, and thus must be explicitly printed on a stat block. Thus you should assume no printed Reach means 5 feet, even for Huge or larger creatures.**

This is further reinforced by the text of the [Enlarge spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=102):

> Bolstered by magical power, the target grows to size Large. Its equipment grows with it but returns to natural size if removed. The creature is clumsy 1. **Its reach increases by 5 feet** (or by 10 feet if it started out Tiny), and

A PC with this spell is presumably now a Large (Tall) creature. Should the above table apply to *all* creatures regardless, then you'd already have a 10 foot reach just for being Large! This would mean Enlarge gives you a 15 foot reach - which I suppose isn't out of the question, but it very clearly seems to be designed to keep PCs on pace with the typical reach of Tall creatures of various sizes. Again, if the typical reach from the table was to be assumed, this text would be unnecessary.

It seems reasonable to say that, RAI, it's left up to the GM to determine whether it makes more sense for the creature that doesn't mention Reach to have the default Reach or the typical Reach - there's a lot that goes into designing a creature, and it's easy for authors to miss small details, especially if they were assumed in other editions.

Comment: What about Groody's answer? "If no reach is given at all, you should assume the default reach as provided in the table, because the rules tell you so."

Comment: @Snakehelm I disagree with the esteemed Groody on what typical means here, I suppose. I tried to address this by showing that Reach is called out even when it's the "typical" amount (the Ogre, or the Enlarge spell) - I'll see if I can make it cleaner.

Comment: RAW, it seems like there is no default reach.  Everything, including the 5 feet "normal" reach is qualified by "typically".

Comment: @Alan yeah, that's a fair observation - a related discussion is ensuing in the comments on Groody's answer.

Comment: I think the best support for this is the exception proving the rule for the reach trait <https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=192>, which states that unarmed attacks with reach have the stated reach instead of allowing only attacks into adjacent spaces.

Answer (score 6):

### Creatures have default reach by size

This is covered in the rules for [size, space and reach](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=445), *core rulebook* page 473:

> Creatures and objects of different sizes occupy different amounts of space. The sizes and the spaces they each take up on a grid are listed in Table 9–1: Size and Reach (page 474). Table 9–1 **also lists the typical reach for creatures of each size**, for both tall creatures (most bipeds) and long creatures (most quadrupeds). See page 455 for more about reach. (...)
> Table 9-1: Size and Reach
>
> | Size | Space | Reach (Tall) | Reach (Long) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Tiny | Less than 5 feet | 0 feet | 0 feet |
> | Small | 5 feet | 5 feet | 5 feet |
> | Medium | 5 feet | 5 feet | 5 feet |
> | Large | 10 feet | 10 feet | 5 feet |
> | Huge | 15 feet | 15 feet | 10 feet |
> | Gargantuan | 20 feet or more | 20 feet | 15 feet |

So yes, Huge creatures *do* have reach just because of their size.

Note that this is given as the **typical** reach. If a creature has different reach stated, it will override these measurements, as specific rules beat general ones. For example, a dragon is not tall, so as a huge creature it would normally have 10 feet reach, but the dragon, with its long neck has 15. A huge creature like the Greater Nightmare would need to say 5 feet, if it wanted to limit you to just that short reach.

If no reach is given at all, you should assume the default reach as provided in the table, because the rules tell you so.

There is no rule (that I am aware of), that states unlisted reach is always 5 feet. The statement under Range and Reach (p. 455 core rules) that says

> **Your reach is typically** 5 feet, but weapons with the reach trait can extend this. Larger creatures can have greater reach;

also uses the term typically and seems to be targeted towards the player characters, who are addressed with *you* and normally have only 5 feet of range unless their weapons change that, but the default reach of monsters is covered by the table listed above. I do however agree that it would be much more convenient if the rules listed the actual reach right there in the stat block for all monsters.

Comment: What about the ESCE's answer? "RAW, Reach is never assumed to be anything but 5 feet, and thus must be explicitly printed on a stat block. Thus you should assume no printed Reach means 5 feet, even for Huge or larger creatures."

Comment: I think the table is pretty clear. I agree with ESCE that the monsters *should* always list the reach, which would make it easier to use, but we are not talking PCs here as the rules do when they say "your reach is typcially 5 feet". The typical reach for monsters of other sizes is not 5 feet instead it it is given in the table. I least I found no statement that an unlisted range would count as 5 feet anywhere. If there was one, I would agree with his read.

Comment: I'm looking for huge creatures and their reaches, and I've found a creature that may be an example of why I might lean towards ESCE's answer: the athach  https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=556  
It wouldn't make sense for the bite attack to have greater reach than the fist attack, right?
I'll keep looking though.

Comment: Interesting - Everywhere I can find for anything, Reach is always discussed in terms of "typical"... I can't find anything that even mentions that PCs have a 5 foot reach by default. That being said, the purpose of Table 9-1 is somewhat unclear anyway as the answerer on [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158421/how-to-determine-if-and-how-a-creatures-reach-should-be-modified-when-its-size) noted.

Comment: @Snakehelm: in the case of the Athach, both the claw and the bite have no listed reach. As a tall, huge creature normal reach would be 15 feet, not 10 by default. As the claw is longer than the arms, it also could make sense to read that as the arms being called out specifially because they have shorter reach. I do agree it seems to make less sense for the bite though, which maybe also should have shorter reach, unless the authors think that the attach bending foward can somehow gain reach out of the height.

Comment: I'd say that since reach is nonetheless a game mechanic, creatures might or might not have it for game balance reasons. In fact, look at the Orca (https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=619) or the Great White Shark (https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=365). Having a greater reach would make them stronger, especially considering their level.
In the meanwhile, two more creatures that make me dubious: Death Coach (https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1852) and Wheel Archon (https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=2079)

Comment: Yeah, this is really seeming like a case of Paizo simply not being clear. I still think the circumstantial evidence (the Athach, monsters having reach listed "unnecessarily" such as the Ogre, the Enlarge spell) leans towards the answer I provide. Best I can find is that the [Reach trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=192) is worded to assume that there's a 5 foot default reach.

Comment: @Snakehelm Wheels don't seem like things that *narratively* would have reach; I would GM those with 5 foot reach myself.

Comment: @ESCE (and Snakehelm, too), I agree with you, narratively reach larger than 5 feet does not make much sense for creatures with not appendices, but while we are at that, neither does even 5 feet. Such creatures narratively would need to bump into their targets with 0 feet reach. If we allow them jumping forward and back 5 feet we could just as well allow them to do it for 10 or 15 feet. I also agree, Paizo is not very clear here.

Comment: Looking at the other end of the spectrum, only a couple (that I could find) tiny creatures list "reach 0" for their melee attacks. If we take ESCE's answer as right, the table 9-1 is blatantly wrong about tiny creatures' typical reach; If we take Groody's answer as right, then the demilitch shouldn't bother listing reach 0 for it's melee strike. It's frustratingly inconsistent either way :/

Comment: @Ruse Which creatures? Maybe there is an explanation

Comment: @Snakehelm the Demilich and Taunting Skull. Both are undead, both are disembodied heads, both have jaw strikes which are explicitly reach 0... but those just seem to be coincidences: just now I also checked the similar Severed Head and it's jaw strike doesn't have an explicit reach.

Comment: On closer inspection, it seems that all the tiny creatures released in the Book of the Dead list reach 0: the Taunting Skull, the Festering Gnasher, the Mummified Cat, and the Predatory Rabbit. The Demilich is from the Bestiary.

Comment: @Ruse It seems normal to me, I checked other a bunch of tiny creatures and they do not say reach 0. After all, the Tiny trait says "They can also occupy the same space as larger creatures, and if their reach is 0 feet, they must do so in order to attack." And IF their reach is 0. That "if" looks important and that to me also seems like doubling down on Delioth's answer on the related question: "the table exists as a general rule or guideline (e.g. for building creatures, or if the GM wants to homebrew a super-enlarge that turns a target gargantuan)".